# Deploying Fields (new or pre-existing) - Security

Tags: deployment, change-set, field-level-security, fls

I haven't been doing Deployments for over a year now in Salesforce *(my role, and company, have significantly changed)*.  However, where I now work, I have developers telling me they CAN NOT DEPLOY SECURITY SETTINGS for their NEWLY CREATED FIELDS when deploying a changeset.  They have to actually create the FLS for all fields AFTER deploying them -- MANUALLY.

At first, they couldn't explain.  Then, they claimed you CAN'T DO THIS at the same time.  At all.  I "knew" this was wrong, and even did a 10 second search...

- [Yes, Dorothy, you can deploy new Fields with FLS](https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000gpIkAAI)

Of course you can (could?!) deploy the Profiles with the new Fields during the same changeset push........

....has this CHANGED?

Does anyone have a clue why a Developer would say this (I keep thinking there is a "more logical" reason why they do not push FLS with the Fields - the Sandboxes are kept up to date regularly).

Thanks for any real-world insight.  ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works the same as it always has. As the answer you linked to states, it does work that way. However, it seems that there's a lot of superstition about how it works, and so most people are "afraid" to use it. I would personally use it all the time to keep permissions in sync, but that "fear" also exists in my environment; we always have to have our deployment coordinator/system admin go in and manually modify field permissions, page layouts, etc. However, I think most of this concern comes from the fact that our QA team tends to make arbitrary changes to layouts and security settings, so we can't depend on them being correct for deployment.